# How to get the datetime from a string containing '2nd' for the date in Python?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I've got a couple strings from which I want to get the datetime. They are formatted like this:

```
Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00
```

I know almost how I can convert this to a datetime, except for that I'm having trouble with the "2**nd**". I now have the following

```
>>> datetime.strptime('Thu 02 May 2013 19:00', '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 2, 19, 0)
```

which works fine with a zero padded number for the day of the month, but when I try the `2nd`, it gives a ValueError:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00', '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00' does not match format '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M'
```

In [the list of datetime directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) I can't find anything relating to ordered values (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc) for dates. Does anybody know how I can get this to work? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Doesn't this help https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple?

Comment: try: `datetime.strptime('Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00', '%a %dnd %B %Y %H:%M')`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the OP mentions multiple strings, what if the date is `3rd` instead?

Comment: @Ffisegydd Yes, your are correct, I mean what you posted is the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider using [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c).

It's a third party library that has a powerful parser which can handle these kinds of things.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = 'Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00'

d = parse(s)
print(d, type(d))
# 2013-05-02 19:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

A brief caveat (doesn't really occur in your case): if `dateutil` can't find an aspect of your date in the string (say you leave out the month) then it will default to the `default` argument. This defaults to the current date with the time 00:00:00. You can obviously over-write this if necessary with a different `datetime` object.

The easiest way to install `dateutil` is probably using [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/) with the command `pip install python-dateutil`.

Comment: The input regarded by the OP is "Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00" not "Thu 02 May 2013 19:00"

Comment: By the way, as you said, it is a third party library, so, for Python beginners, such as me, could you tell us how could I install it to the Python?

Comment: @sємsєм - Just do a `sudo pip install python-dateutil`. If you don't have pip installed, read here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Answer (score 5):

You can preparse the original string to adjust the day to be suitable for your `strptime`, eg:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

s = 'Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00'
amended = re.sub('\d+(st|nd|rd|th)', lambda m: m.group()[:-2].zfill(2), s)
# Thu 02 May 2013 19:00
dt = datetime.strptime(amended, '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M')
# 2013-05-02 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

It's straightforward to remove the suffix from the date without using regular expressions or an external library.

```
def remove_date_suffix(s):
    parts = s.split()
    parts[1] = parts[1].strip("stndrh") # remove 'st', 'nd', 'rd', ...
    return " ".join(parts)
```

Then it's as simple as using `strptime` as you'd expect:

```
>>> s = "Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00"
>>> remove_date_suffix(s)
'Thu 2 May 2013 19:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(remove_date_suffix(s), '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 2, 19, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
def proc_date(x):
    return re.sub(r"\b([0123]?[0-9])(st|th|nd|rd)\b",r"\1",x)

>>> x='Thu 2nd May 2013 19:00'
>>> proc_date(x)
'Thu 2 May 2013 19:00'
>>> datetime.strptime(proc_date(x), '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 2, 19, 0)
```