# Parse and group multiple items together using Pyparse

Tags: python, pyparsing

This is a build up on [Build a simple parser that is able to parse different date formats using PyParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113532/build-a-simple-parser-that-is-able-to-parse-different-date-formats-using-pyparse)

I have a parser that should group one or more users together into a list
So `a.parser('show abc, xyz commits from "Jan 10,2015" to "27/1/2015"')` should group the two usernames into a list [abc,xyz]

For users I have:

```
keywords = ["select", "show", "team", "from", "to", "commits", "and", "or"]
    [select, show, team, _from, _to,  commits, _and, _or] = [ CaselessKeyword(word) for word in keywords ]

user = Word(alphas+"."+alphas)
user2 = Combine(user + "'s")
users = OneOrMore((user|user2))
```

And the grammar is

```
bnf = (show|select)+Group(users).setResultsName("users")+Optional(team)+(commits).setResultsName("stats")\
    +Optional(_from + quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)('from') +\
    _to + quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)('to'))
```

This is erroneous. Can anyone guide me in the right direction.
Also, is there a way in pyparse to selectively decide which group the word should fall under. What I mean is that 'xyz' standalone should go under my user list. But 'xyz team' should go under a team list. If the optional keyword team is provided then pyparse should group it differently.

I haven't been able to find what I am looking for online. Or maybe I haven't been framing my question correctly on Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, see the embedded comments in this update to your parser:

```
from pyparsing import *

keywords = ["select", "show", "team", "from", "to", "commits", "and", "or"]
[select, show, team, _from, _to,  commits, _and, _or] = [ CaselessKeyword(word) for word in keywords ]

# define an expression to prevent matching keywords as user names - used below in users expression
keyword = MatchFirst(map(CaselessKeyword, keywords))

user = Word(alphas+"."+alphas)  # ??? what are you trying to define here?
user2 = Combine(user + "'s")
# must not confuse keywords like commit with usernames - and use ungroup to 
# unpack single-element token lists
users = ungroup(~keyword + (user|user2))

#~ bnf = (show|select)+Group(users).setResultsName("users")+Optional(team)+(commits).setResultsName("stats") \
    #~ + Optional(_from + quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)('from') +
                    #~ _to + quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)('to'))

def convertToDatetime(tokens):
    # change this code to do your additional parsing/conversion to a Python datetime
    return tokens[0] 
timestamp = quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes, convertToDatetime)

# similar to your expression
# - use delimitedList instead of OneOrMore to handle comma-separated list of items
# - add distinction of "xxx team" vs "xxx"
# - dropped expr.setResultsName("name") in favor of short notation expr("name")
# - results names with trailing '*' will accumulate like elements into a single
#   named result (short notation for setResultsName(name, listAllValues=True) )
# - dropped setResultsName("stats") on keyword "commits", no point to this, commits must always be present
#
bnf = ((show|select)("command") + delimitedList(users("team*") + team | users("user*")) + commits + 
            Optional(_from + timestamp('from') + _to + timestamp('to')))

test = 'show abc, def team, xyz commits from "Jan 10,2015" to "27/1/2015"'

print bnf.parseString(test).dump()
```

Prints:

```
['show', 'abc', 'def', 'team', 'xyz', 'commits', 'from', 'Jan 10,2015', 'to', '27/1/2015']
- command: show
- from: Jan 10,2015
- team: ['def']
- to: 27/1/2015
- user: ['abc', 'xyz']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time out to help me. As for the definition of users, its just how the usernames are defined. Its always firstname.lastname and hence my definition. If I have any further questions do I continue on this thread or create a seperate post?

Comment: `Word(alphas+"."+alphas)` will accept any word group of alphas and '.'s, like "a.b.c...d.ddd". If you want `firstname.lastname`, change to `Combine(Word(alphas) + '.' + Word(alphas))`.  Or to match your test code, use `Combine(Word(alphas) + Optional('.' + Word(alphas)))`
SO discourages long chains of comments - if you have further questions about pyparsing, open new posts.