# How to parse and return a hierarchy of keywords?

Tags: pyparsing

The keywords for a command I want to parse have a hierarchy, for example:

the keywords `'aaa'` and `'bbb'` would belong to `'product1'` and `'ccc'` and `'ddd'` would belong to `'product2'`. Overall `'product1'` and `'product2'` belong to `'product'`.

When the user inputs a string such as `'ccc run X'` I want the parser to output as part of the dump:

```
Product: product2
```

I tried to think based on [Parse and group multiple items together using Pyparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222223/parse-and-group-multiple-items-together-using-pyparse) how to construct this heirarchy but can't seem to think of solution... can someone please point to a relevant example of pyparse elements suitable for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a parse action is the best place to add items like this to the tokens. In the body of a parse action that gets the tokens passed in, you can add new named results just by using the dict interface on the tokens to add it.

I mocked up this simple parser to parse your command:

```
import pyparsing as pp

cmd_prefix = pp.oneOf("aaa bbb ccc ddd")
action_expr = pp.oneOf("run hold cancel submit pause resume")
cmd_expr = (cmd_prefix("prefix") 
            + action_expr("action") 
            + pp.empty() + pp.restOfLine("qualifiers"))
```

Running your sample command as a test:

```
cmd_expr.runTests("""\
    aaa run X
    """)
```

Gives:

```
aaa run X
['aaa', 'run', 'X']
- action: 'run'
- prefix: 'aaa'
- qualifiers: 'X'
```

We can add a parse action to your cmd_expr to embellish the results with additional entries. To keep the code and data separate, here is a dict that defines a few added items based on the prefix:

```
prefix_items = {
    'aaa': {'Product': 'product1', 'Material':  'paper', },
    'bbb': {'Product': 'product1', 'Material':  'wool', },
    'ccc': {'Product': 'product2', 'Material':  'wood', },
    'ddd': {'Product': 'product2', 'Material':  'plastic', },
    }
```

And this parse action will add them to the parsed results:

```
def add_prefix_items(tokens):
    # find dict of items to add
    adders = prefix_items.get(tokens.prefix, {})

    # for each key-value in dict, add to the parsed tokens
    for name, value in adders.items():
        tokens[name] = value

cmd_expr.addParseAction(add_prefix_items)
```

Here are some more tests and output:

```
cmd_expr.runTests("""\
    aaa run X
    ddd hold Z
    eee resume A
    """)
```

Gives:

```
aaa run X
['aaa', 'run', 'X']
- Material: 'paper'
- Product: 'product1'
- action: 'run'
- prefix: 'aaa'
- qualifiers: 'X'


ddd hold Z
['ddd', 'hold', 'Z']
- Material: 'plastic'
- Product: 'product2'
- action: 'hold'
- prefix: 'ddd'
- qualifiers: 'Z'

eee resume A
^
FAIL: Expected aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

If this list gets long, you might end up having to read it from a database of some kind. Here is a little in-memory database example (using another open source lib of mine, littletable):

```
import littletable as lt

# create simple in-memory database table, indexed by item
prefix_items = lt.Table().create_index('prefix').csv_import("""\
prefix,name,value
aaa,Product,product1
aaa,Material,paper
bbb,Product,product1
bbb,Material,wool
ccc,Product,product2
ccc,Material,wood
ddd,Product,product2
ddd,Material,plastic
""")

def add_prefix_items_from_table(t):
    # get all entries in the table with matching key
    # (in a SQL database, this would be some kind of SELECT query)
    adders = prefix_items.by.prefix[t.prefix]

    # for each matching record, add the item-value to the parsed tokens
    for rec in adders:
        t[rec.name] = rec.value

# clear previous parse action and add new one
cmd_expr.setParseAction()
cmd_expr.addParseAction(add_prefix_items_from_table)
```

Gives same results as shown previously.

Comment: Wow, such an awesome answer, many thanks for taking the time to write and explain things so clearly! Also happy to learn about littletable