# Python Identify (Convert) text to date

Tags: python, date, formatting

I am trying to find best way to convert "Friday 1st March 2019" or "Saturday 2nd March 2019" to python datetime object.

I tried by splitting, than had thoughts on regex, but I am quite sure there is more 'elegant' way ofdoing it

From string "Friday 1st March 2019" I expect 01-03-2019 or 2019-03-01

TNX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not the "best" way, but a very easy way is [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Friday 1st March 2019")
```

Returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

It can pretty much be wrapped up as:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strftime(parser.parse("Friday 1st March 2019"), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Returning:

```
'01-03-2019'
```

Comment: Exactly what I have been asking for! Thank you tgikal!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to face issues with `1st`, `2nd`.

So, try this (without adding any external/third party library):

```
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt
ds = "Friday 1st March 2019"
parts = ds.split(" ")
ds = "{} {} {} {}".format(
   parts[0],
   re.sub('[^0-9]','', parts[1]),
   parts[2],
   parts[3]
)
a = dt.strptime(ds, "%A %d %B %Y")
```

If you want to make it into a function, do this:

```
def convdate(s):
    parts = s.split(" ")
    ds = "{} {} {} {}".format(
        parts[0],
        re.sub('[^0-9]','', parts[1]),
        parts[2],
        parts[3]
    )
    return dt.strptime(ds, "%A %d %B %Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to an already answered question:
[How to get the datetime from a string containing '2nd' for the date in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091947/how-to-get-the-datetime-from-a-string-containing-2nd-for-the-date-in-python)

As I can only repeat, solution is to use dateutil parser:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

your_string = "Friday 1st March 2019"
date_obj = parse(your_string)
```

Behind the scenes, I guess the "1st", and "2nd" parts are extracted somehow (e.g. splitting+regex) and simplified to its day value only. 
According to an input like that, the common datetime library can be used with proper date format string:

```
import datetime
simplified_txt = "Friday 1 March 2019"
datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(simplified_txt,"%A %d %B %Y")
```